# Where in my query to place the CONVERT to convert DateTime to Date

Tags: sql, date, datetime

Just learning SQL and I've searched many options about converting a DateTime into a Date, and I do not want current date. It's a super simple query from this website: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Easy

```
SELECT booking_date, nights
FROM booking
WHERE guest_id=1183
```

But the output is with the timestamp and I just want the date. I've searched so many forums and tried all their suggestions, including this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), <col>, 101)
```

So I've done:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), booking_date,101), nights
FROM booking
WHERE guest_id=1183
```

But I'm getting syntax errors. This is probably so simple and you'll all think me an idiot, but I'd greatly appreciate help. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: What database system are you actually using? Tag appropriately. SQL is a family of dialects; what you're using here is T-SQL, as used by SQL Server, but there are others.

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own quirks in the way it handles dates and times. You're using MS SQL Server it looks like. Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I fiddled about at your sqlzoo link I got the error

> execute command denied to user 'scott'@'localhost' for routine 'gisq.to_date'`.

When I googled *gisq.to_date* I got this link https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Format_a_date_and_time

Which has examples of how this dialect represents dates. See if you can work it out. Something like this:

```
SELECT date_format(booking_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
FROM booking
```

You didn't post the error in your question which is a big mistake. When you get an error message, you actually have something to work from.

It is also **very important** to note that the query above returns a string, not a date. It's only good for display, not for date arithmetic

TBH that seems like a terrible site to learn on as it gives no clues about the dialect. it looks like Oracle but `to_date` and `trunc` don't work.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I have much to learn. Getting there

Answer (score 1):

The use of `convert()` suggests that you think you are uinsg SQL Server.  If you only want the date component of a date/time data type, then you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, booking_date), nights
FROM booking
WHERE guest_id = 1183;
```

The syntax error suggests that you are not using SQL Server.
`CONVERT()` is bespoke syntax for SQL Server.  Examples of similar functionality in other databases are:

```
DATE(booking_date)
TRUNC(booking_date)
DATE_TRUNC('day', booking_date)
```

In addition, what you see also depends on the user-interface.
In your case, the data is being stored as a date with no time component, but the UI is showing the time.  For that, you want to convert to a string.  That site uses MariaDB -- which is really a flavor of MySQL-- and you would use:

```
DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```